Swift @Observable vs Observable protocol
What's the difference between @Observable and conforming to Observable? Are they functionally equivalent?
@Observable class MyClass { ... }

class MyClass: Observable { ... }


I don’t understand what your code has to do with SwiftData but generally you should use the former code example.

@JoakimDanielson Why should you use the former?

Because with the macro swift will observe each object you create, in the second case you are only conforming to a protocol but nothing will be done during runtime to your objects

This is a big topic, which is also one of the core concepts of Swift, and so you need to properly understand it to use SwiftUI. So I suggest, rather than relying on SO answer, research it. Apple provided numerous resources for that. For example: this, this, and this

@Observable is a macro and Observable is a protocol
Observable

Conforming to this protocol signals to other APIs that the type supports observation. However, applying the Observable protocol by itself to a type doesn’t add observation functionality to the type.

@Observable

This macro adds observation support to a custom type and conforms the type to the Observable protocol.

Always use the Observable() macro when adding observation support to a type.

See also: Migrating from the Observable Object protocol to the Observable macro
